# Multindex add zero values if no in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, indexing

I have a pandas (v.0.23.4) dataframe with multindex('date', 'class').

```
                  Col_values
date       class            
2019-04-30 0             324
           1            6874
           2              44
           3               5
           4              15
2019-05-31 0             393
           1            6534
           2              64
           3               1
           4              22
2019-06-30 0             325
           1            5899
           2              48
           4               7
```

In '2019-06-30' class 3 is missing because there are no data. 
What I want is to add class 3 in the multindex and zero values in the Col_values column automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) with `fill_value=0` with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = df.unstack(fill_value=0).stack()
print (df)
                  Col_values
date       class            
2019-04-30 0             324
           1            6874
           2              44
           3               5
           4              15
2019-05-31 0             393
           1            6534
           2              64
           3               1
           4              22
2019-06-30 0             325
           1            5899
           2              48
           3               0
           4               7
```

Another solution is use [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) with [`MultiIndex.from_product`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.from_product.html):

```
mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product(df.index.levels, names=df.index.names)
df = df.reindex(mux, fill_value=0)
print (df)
                  Col_values
date       class            
2019-04-30 0             324
           1            6874
           2              44
           3               5
           4              15
2019-05-31 0             393
           1            6534
           2              64
           3               1
           4              22
2019-06-30 0             325
           1            5899
           2              48
           3               0
           4               7
```